# Octave division of a binomial breaks plot

Tags: plot, octave, gnuplot

I am not sure if this is the correct stack exchange for this question. I normally use javascript and a canvas to graph an equation. I am trying out Octave. I am having trouble getting any function with the same variable on both sides of a division to render. Test equation:

```
x=0:1:512;
Vr=x/100;
clf;
plot((50*Vr.^2-200*Vr)/(Vr-3), 'k-', 'linewidth', 3.0);
axis([0 512 -256 256]);
```

It works just fine without the division:

```
plot((50*Vr.^2-200*Vr), 'k-', 'linewidth', 3.0);
```

Screenscrapes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWnWi.jpg
The third is the equation with the division rendered with javascript.

Does octave not support this rather basic arithmetic, or is there a syntax eccentricity that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

As much as I hate to be the guy who answers his own question, I found the answer in octave's docs.

https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Arithmetic-Ops.html

'/' Multiplies the left by the inverse of the right. Seemed right, as the opposite of the (Vr/3) sounds like what I wanted, until I read on. './' is "Element-by-element right division." So the plot function treats Vr as a matrix of all the coordinates and computes a matrix with one equation. That was not clear in any of the documentation I read. Seriously, this should have been in the top level help section.

So "syntax eccentricity" it is. The correct syntax for octave is:

```
plot((50*Vr.^2-200*Vr)./(Vr-3), 'k-', 'linewidth', 3.0)
```

This works. I think I'll stick to JS though, if only to avoid needing to transform my equations to and from octave's weird syntax. Still, it's nice to have a non-browser-dependent option handy, however eccentric.

Comment: The two ways of handling division exist because sometimes you want to multiply by the inverse matrix and other times you want to compute the element-by-element division.